# How to set Runtime Library (MT/MD) configuration in MSBuild?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I build old external project. Say I do not have a visual IDE - only MSbuild (like one you get in  AppVeyour). How to pass MD\MT in MSbuild?

Currently to compile VS2010 project using VS2015 I use:
`${MSBUILD_COMMAND} solution.sln /p:PlatformToolset=v140 /p:configuration=Release /p:platform "x64" /project "project-lib"`
Yet I would like also to set runtime library configuration from MSbuild command. How to do it?

Comment: I think those /p options are only selection, not settings. You could select configurations exist in project files already. MD/MT are included in each configuration of the projects, so you might not able to select them unless you have prepared different configurations for different MD/MT settings. For example, some projects I saw them use ReleaseMD, ReleaseMT, DebugMD, DebugMT, etc.